# How to use 2D arrays inside a C struct?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, struct

I need to create a struct that holds a 2D array however the array size can vary so i cannot define it with a  constant length. I tried to solve this with a double pointer only to find out the double pointer is not the same as a double array. So how can i do this?

```
struct GaussianKernel {
   int r;
   double weightSum;
   double **kernel;
};

GaussianKernel initializeKernel2D(jdouble sigma){
   int r = (int) ceil(3 * sigma);
   int kernelLen = 2 * r + 1;
   double G[kernelLen][kernelLen];
   double weightSum = 0;
   double temp;

   for (int y = -r; y <= r; y++)
   {
      for (int x = -r; x <= r; x++)
      {
         temp =  exp(-(pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2)) / (2 * pow(sigma, 2))) / (2 * PI * pow(sigma, 2));
         G[y + r][x + r] = temp;
         weightSum = weightSum + temp;
      }
   }

   struct GaussianKernel GKernel;
   GKernel.r = r;
   GKernel.kernel = G;
   GKernel.weightSum = weightSum;

   return GKernel;
}
```

Comment: Note that your code tried to return a pointer to a local variable — that is horribly wrong. You will need to use dynamic allocation. How much control do you have over where this structure is used? What will you be passing to functions that you didn't write?  One option is simply to allocate a suitably-sized vector of `double` values and then index that with expressions `gk->kernel[row * (2 * gk->r + 1) + col]` (instead of `gk->kernel[row][col]`), though you'd do better to record the array size explicitly in the structure.  That's more or less trivial. The alternatives, if available, are messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu should allocate your 2D dynamic array as:

```
GKernel.kernel = malloc(kernelLen * sizeof(double *));
for(i=0;i<kernelLen;i++)
GKernel.kernel[i] = malloc(kernelLen * sizeof(double));
```

Then you can store values in `GKernel.kernel` as per logic of your program

Comment: To quote the question: _I tried to solve this with a double pointer only to find out the double pointer is not the same as a double array._  This answer looks remarkably like using a double pointer.

Comment: True, I agree double array and array of pointers are different